# How can I make a 3G video call (not Facetime) from an iPhone 4 to another brand's 3G phone?

Tags: iphone, video, call

How can I make a 3G video call (not Facetime) from an iPhone 4 to another brand's 3G phone? Is it possible by default? or any apps?

Edit 11 November:

I just found this today: [No 3G video calling on iPhone 4](http://www.themobileindian.com/news/1349_No-3G-video-calling-on-iPhone-4)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [Skype](http://www.skype.com) for that, if the app allows 3G video-chat. Skype is available for a lot of platforms. When you are at home, you can also use Skype on your computer so you don't have to use your (probably limited) 3G network.

Comment: To phone which I want to call doesn't have Skype but that has video call facility and Skype need internet I'm taking about without Wi-fi internet. When I'm on road

Answer (score 2):

If you mean standard 3G video calls (3G-324M) then no, the iPhone does not support these (and I doubt any (legal) 3rd party apps would be allowed that deep inside the phone).

If the other party does not have any other possibilities besides 3G video call, then I guess your only possibility would be to get yourself a phone that supports that.

Answer (score 0):

[Fring](http://www.fring.com/) supports many phone types. iPhone, Android, Nokia phones supporting the Ovi store, and many "classic" phones with support for mobile Java.

[Tango](http://www.tango.me/) also competes in this space by catering to iPhone, Android, and even Desktops/Laptops, though apparently Windows-only at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I use Qik, made by Skype: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qik-video/id439715497?mt=8 Its product page says "Compatible with iPhones, iPod Touches that have a built-in cameras and iPad 2's with iOS4+. Place live video calls with other Qik users on iOS4+ devices **or on Android 2.1- Android 2.3.3 phones** (93% of all Android phones)."

I just got the Qik app and only have tested it once, but it worked fine over 3G on Verizon network.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile devices dont allow 3G connections. According to my understanding, VOIP like Skype won't function on 3G either. Video calling requires a stable net connection which 3G definitely isn't, at least in most countries. Hopefully 4G technology will take care of this recurring problem.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately Facetime is only available for Apple devices and a Mac running Snow Leopard.

You can try [Skype?](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8)

This is free to users, by downloading the app and informing your friend of the apps function, you will be able to essentially have a Facetime call. Best of all, you will be able to use an existing Skype account which means if you already have one you will get all your contacts, credits, and data.

Comment: Please add more information than just a name and a link. Yes, it may answer the question, but add more information please.